# Accessing IBM API Connect endpoint through Postman

Tags: rest, api, postman, apiconnect, apic

I just created an REST API in API Connect and the endpoint works when I test it in the APIC assemble tab.  It requires a client id and client secret.  When I send a request through Postman, I currently get a “Could not get any response” message from when I try to add them as header values or OAuth authorization.  I’m using the request endpoint that’s displayed when I hit the debug button from the successful response on the Assemble tab.  Is this the correct endpoint to use?  How do I properly include the client id and client secret in a Postman request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include the client id and client secret in the headers using the correct name for them, which is specified when creating/editing the api under the 'Security Definitions' category as 'Parameter Name'.

I was also hitting the wrong endpoint.  To find the correct endpoint click the hamburger icon in the upper left of api connect website, select dashboard, click on the environment you want such as sandbox or dev, click settings, click gateway, then you'll see the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a "Could not get any response in Postman", that means that Postman can't reach the destination of the request.
[image: No response]

There are several reasons for that:

- Is it an intranet or internet endpoint?
- Are you using a proxy? (check proxy config)
- Is the hostname resolvable? (try ip)
- If it is an https
  endpoint, with a self signed certificate, check if you have SSL
  Certificate verification enabled (Settings-> general)

On the other hand, to send the client-id and client-secret headers, just click on Headers tab and add both (see the following picture)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below things to get access to API Connect published services.

- Service needs to be allowed to invoke from postman(System from which you are invoking.)
- Please check the web-api MPGW service titled in DataPower default domain created when you configure your API connect with DataPower have you created an access control list in the front-side-handler.
- Please disable the SSL configuration in the postman, sometime this may create a problem(since the service exposed from API Connect will be with SSL)

From the error you are getting, I suspect there is no connection or only one-way traffic is enabled which means you are blocking response. If there is an issue with the request parameters you are sending, an error will be different saying, wrong client id or client secret.

Testing API which is on-boarded from API Connect will be straightforward or same we invoke other rest services.

Thx Srikanth